# How can I disable autosave since it is causing lag spikes?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Minecraft freezes so much that it is unplayable, even though I get a good 5 FPS at minimum graphics settings.

There is no option to disable "auto saving" option in minecraft, and I wish there is. Is there any way to disable auto saving? I have forge installed so I can use mods to turn it off.

Comment: are u 100% sure autosave is even the problem?

Comment: Minecraft is almost 10 years old. There's some serious problems if you are having 5 FPS during regular play. Is it happening with a new world too?

Comment: "A good 5 fps?" That's a typo, right? Anyway, do you happen to run the experimental builds with the data-pack for the new cave content installed? In that case: There is [a common issue with hickups on walking across chunk borders](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MC-162253?focusedCommentId=981143&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-981143) which also makes my latest world pretty unplayable. That's not related to the autosave system, but could be mistaken for such.

Comment: Autosave happens every 40 seconds. Do these freezes happen every 40 seconds? If not, autosave is not at fault.

Comment: @Nelson 5 FPS is still absolute trash but just because it's 10 years old means nothing. Minecraft can run at a slightly higher FPS than a CoD game for me, because it uses Java and is terribly slow. If he has that I'm guessing he has his settings maxed out on a laptop thats low or mid tier

Comment: Autosaves are the problem because the freezes are not random
It's also not when crossing chunk borders, because it also occurs when I am standing still and doing stuff

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't disable them, however you can change how often Minecraft autosaves with [OptiFine](https://optifine.net/home).

Find the setting under `Main Menu => Options => Video Settings => Other => Autosave Interval` (bottom-most button).